# Intellij Maven dependency not found (sqlite-jdbc)

Tags: java, sqlite, maven

IntelliJ Maven `pom.xml` I get the following message:

> Dependency org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.1 not found.

How can I fix my problem? This is the only dependency in my `pom.xml` which doesn't work.

[image]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have the same problem. I think I'll try my luck with changing the database next. By the way, the development environment can communicate with sqlite and execute sqls.

Answer (score 0):

Check correctness artifact properties as group artifact and version, if they correct this mean your artifact is not in maven central repo you need manually add new repository in you pom.xml where this artifact present. If you artifact in maven central try to load them manually if you use maven not bundled in intellij install 
-> open console in idea with `alt + f12` then type `mvn dependency:resolve`

update

your artifact in central repo, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.11.1
Sometimes i meet this bug in Idea (Idea does not see this dependency because it does not indexed by Idea or something like this, version of artifact highlight red but it is only idea deal) add manually this dependency or try to recheck (clear caches) and all will be work.

Answer (score 0):

after testing in a new Maven Test Project, it works now in my main projec. Thank